# TSQL Update variable only if there is a value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have an `update` statement that looks like this:

```
UPDATE  sessions
SET currentStep      = @currentStep,
    chosenDepartment = @chosenDepartment,
    proposedTimes    = @proposedTimes
WHERE   sessionID = @sessionID
    AND empID = @empID;
```

I use the same stored procedure for multiple updates as each step in my process gets an additional value along the way.

My question: is there a way to only do this :

```
chosenDepartment = @chosenDepartment
```

if `@cosenDepartment` actually contains a value?

If I do it every time, it will overwrite it with blank data if I don't pass anything to it.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
UPDATE  sessions
SET currentStep      = @currentStep,
    chosenDepartment = CASE WHEN @chosenDepartment IS NOT NULL THEN @chosenDepartment ELSE chosenDepartment END,
    proposedTimes    = @proposedTimes
WHERE   sessionID = @sessionID
    AND empID = @empID;
```

or this

```
UPDATE  sessions
SET currentStep      = @currentStep,
    chosenDepartment = COALESCE(@chosenDepartment, chosenDepartment),
    proposedTimes    = @proposedTimes
WHERE   sessionID = @sessionID
    AND empID = @empID;
```

Note #1:  SQL Server will translate `COALESCE(@chosenDepartment, chosenDepartment)`
into `CASE WHEN @chosenDepartment IS NOT NULL THEN @chosenDepartment ELSE chosenDepartment END`.

Note #2: If you want to avoid NULL `@chosenDepartment` but also if you want to avoid the updates with empty strings or `0` then you could use `NULLIF` function thus: `COALESCE(NULLIF(@chosenDepartment,''), chosenDepartment)` or `COALESCE(NULLIF(@chosenDepartment,0), chosenDepartment)`.

Answer (score 0):

You may put if statement before tsql so if @chosenDepartment is blank then tsql won't run.

Comment: It wont run the query at all or just that value ?

Comment: It wont run query at all whenever your parameter is blank. That is what you want isn't it?

Comment: I dont want it to run the value that is blank. If i dont pass anything to /@chosenDepartment then    chosenDepartment = @chosenDepartment, will not insert anything but the rest of the values that were passed will insert as normal

Comment: Update - I use the same stored procedure for steps 1-5 of my tool. Each step, we get another piece of data and add it to the record. However if I tell do  var1 = @var and we dont get \@var until step 5, then its going to keep overwriting it in steps 1-4 with blank data as we dont have a value yet.